# Present modal view controller from the right

Tags: iphone, ios5, transition, presentmodalviewcontroller

I want to present modally a view controller, with transition from the right to left (exactly like a Navigation Controller). But I don't want to use any navigation controllers at ALL. Also when I will dismiss the presented view controller, I want the animation to be from left to right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using **IIViewDeckController**: https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

You can use it the way, you set **centerController** to you "modal controller" you want to present, your **leftController** to your current controller and at the start you show left controller by default. When you want to show your modal controller, just show the center one.

That is what you want

Comment: Thank you. But what I am trying to achieve is something similar like in the Email app. In my "rootViewController" I can perform a search, when a tap un the UISearchBar I hide the navigation bar. Then, I can press on one of the cells with the results and I want to push a new view controller from the right, that will have the navigation bar, but unfortunately the new navigation controller is pushed from the right and the navigation bar is animated from top. I want both the navigation bar and the new view controller to be animated from right to left.

Comment: If I understand it right, you want to new controller to slide from right to left above previous view controller. You can achieve it using IIDeckViewController. Your normal controller is on its left controller and you new modal controller on its center. Then you can animate presenting the modal controller. Take look at this video and you will see:https://vimeo.com/34538429

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add a UINavigationController as centerViewController.

Comment: are you sure? UINavigationController is subclass o UIViewController. i am using custom UIViewController as a center view controller and it works perfect

Comment: Yes, I get an error that the parrent of UINavigationController should be nil, not IIDeckViewController.

Comment: Maybe you can try a little hack. Use **UITabBarController** with one navigation controller and hide tabbar. Or you can do it like I do. I have custom view controller with my **UINavigationController** as property and I set my view controller's view = my **UINavigationController's** view. Hope it helps!

Comment: You can definitely add a UINavigationController as a centerViewController with ViewDeck